# Auto format iframe width & height

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a text field which I would like customers fill their YouTube video with. The YouTube video share coding is an `iframe` and normally it takes value like `width=560`, `height=315`.

Now, if the customer pasted the `iframe` code into my text field, then the `560 width` will be a problem as this width is too much for responsive design, when stretch down to mobile size, the `iframe` problem will show.

I now need **jQuery** code which, when the customer fills in the `iframe`, will automatically format the width and height down to `width=230`, `height=160`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitvid is a great plugin for this: http://fitvidsjs.com/

However, there are other pure css methods available using out div that constrain iframe proportions by using padding for responsive layouts.

Comment: No problem at all, this link may be useful too: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php